# How to maintain different session in different tabs?

Tags: list, custom-web-parts

We are working on a custom web part in which data is fetched from different SharePoint lists in to a static datatable based on the name of the SharePoint list . But when i open same web part , from different tabs , it is showing same data . Can anybody tell me how to maintain different SharePoint session in different tab for custom web part ?

Any kind of help will be appreciable .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today where i wanted to view a web part with a different kind of SharePoint account. What i tried:

-Tried to log in as a different SharePoint user, in a different browser session, with Internet explorer. But the newest IE removed that option.

-Tried virtual desktop view to log into a different windows account so i could use a different SharePoint account to view the web part.

The last solution worked for me. But its only a suggestion because i don't know if it gives you a different session like you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks for instant reply Norman . I am fetching the list data into custom  webpart in c# . When ever I tried to debug the webpart opening 2 different lists in 2 different IE tabs , it is showing same list data in c# code .

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy in IE 11. Maybe that is for all versions of IE.
When you open your SharePoint location, click on right mouse button than SHIFT+left mouse button on **Internet explorer** icon in taskbar. Be sure not to click on SharePoint opened tabs, but on IE name. You can see it on image bellow text, beneath **Properties** on pop up menu.
After that IE will ask you for credentials and when you enter credentials, paste desired SharePoint URL.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see your question mentioned, you are using static data table. 
The static variables refer the same memory location. Try to remove static and use instance variable and try it should work.
You should be very careful when using static keyword in C#.